# Controller is being hit multiple times - spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are developing application using spring3MVC framework. We have a functinality to create, update and delete the reocords  and for each scenario mails have to be sent to the users when the record is created or updated or deleted. But one issue is when iam creating internally its hitting controller multiple times and mails are sent multiple times to the users. How can we prevent hitting the controller multiple times. When iam debuging i can see the control is hitting the controller multiple times. Do i need to modify any thing in xml configuration files.
Below is the sample code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createRecord", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView insertRecord(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute("requestDTO") ATRRequestDTO dto,
        BindingResult beException,
        @RequestParam("buttonName") String buttonName,
        @RequestParam("id") String atrID) throws IOException {

    // create session if its not available
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    try{
        //code to insert the data if not exists
        if(conditinal check){
            sendMail();//if succesfully inserted record mail will be sent
        }
        mav.setViewName("atrRequest");
        mav.addObject("dataBean", dataBean);
        return mav;
    } catch(Exception e) { }
    return mav;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean about 'But one issue is when iam creating internally its hitting controller multiple times and mails are sent multiple times to the users'? Post some code

Comment: included the code above..

Comment: But why this is hit multiple times? What do you mean about creating internally? Sorry but it is not easy to understand.. for me :)

Comment: Probably your client code is creating multiple requests so you will need to modify that.

Comment: @participantjava,were you able to reach a solution to this problem,I'm facing a somewhat similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way the controller can be hit multiple times is if the client is calling the controller multiple times.

You will need to debug the calling code to see why the mutiple calls are made, it might be the user refreshing the browser during the sending of a mail, clicking multiple times on a button while the previous request is still being processed.

Try to disable actions in the user interface while the response to the ajax request is not yet received, and reenable them again once the response to the previous request is received.